# Blank Reports for Sitecore Analytics

Tags: experience-analytics, mongodb, experience-profile

We have empty reports in Sitecore Experience Dashboard on one of the environments where we have 1 CM and 2 CD servers and we have tried out various things but nothing worked.

Reports look something like this
[image: Empty search result]

1) We need to track Anonymous user so

```
"ContentSearch.Analytics.IndexAnonymousContacts" value="true"
```

2) enableAnalytics at Site level is set to true

3) We have got these settings in place `<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" /> and <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />`

4) Check ReportDataView there is lots of Data in there in that View

All I see in logs there are two kinds of entries

Error 1 :

```
Tracker.IsActive == false. EndAnalytics pipeline is terminated
Tracker is not initialized. ReleaseContact processor is skipped
```

Error 2:

```
Cannot submit pending item: MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException: QueryFailure flag was Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34089254 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes (response was { "$err" : "Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34089254 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes", "code" : 17144 })
```

I ran this command even error is still same ;

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes:50151432})
```

Any clue what to do here.